# Unexpected end of input in Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function:

```
<script>
    function jQueryAjaxForm(form) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            var ajaxConfig = {
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.action,
                data: new FormData(form),
                success: null
            }
            if ($(form).attr('enctype') == "multipart/form-data") {
                ajaxConfig["contentType"] = false;
                ajaxConfig["processData"] = false;
            }
            $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
        }
}
</script>
```

And I'm getting the error at the closing `</script>` tag.
I've checked all brackets and still have yet to figure out whats wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try adding `processData: false,` to the ajaxConfig

Comment: Try recreating your issue.  eg in a new project or in a stack snippet or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7r05es8/).   There's no syntax (missing brackets/quotes) in what you've provided and it parses on jsfiddle.